# What commands do I need to tell my team to use to update their tags?

Tags: git

I have recently had to completely delete and make new our Git tags due to a change on GitHub. It says in the Git that you need to follow certain instructions to get users to update existing tags. However, I deleted all of my tags and made new ones with different names. What commands do I need to get my team to use to delete their existing tags and pull the new ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy to just delete all local tags and re-fetch new ones from the remote, then you can use these two commands:

```
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
git fetch --prune
```